# Как лучше хранить одинаковые значения полей в БД?

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Есть БД, в которой многие таблицы имеют одинаковое поле **type** в которой только 2 параметра (допустим **'car'**:**'bike'**). 
Как лучше хранить эти параметры?:
1. Создать отдельную таблицу и прописывать id
2. Создать поле enum для каждой таблицы).

Comment: не понял. у вас два параметра в _одном_ поле ?

Comment: Если один из двух - ENUM. Если ни одного, один или два - SET.

Comment: не понял. у вас два параметра в одном поле ? - нет, поле может принимать значение либо car либо bike

Comment: Если один из двух - ENUM. Если ни одного, один или два - SET. - вопрос был как лучше хранить эти параметры(отдельной таблицей или прописывать в каждой enum)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё от ваших бизнес требований зависит:

1. Когда/Если надо будет добавить значение в `enum` в большой и часто используемой (миллионы записей) таблице. То придется останавливать приложение.
2. Если отдельная таблица, то это еще одна таблица которую надо содержать(а также `join`'s  ...), которая содержит просто константы.
3. Как вариант(второй с половиной), не идеальный, можно вынести константы в код и оставить коментарий к столбцу какие значения что значат, но тогда теряеться связь между значениeм и смыслом. Если просто смотреть данные, не понятно что они значат без кода.

Короче вам решать зависет от бизнес цели.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Сейчас в рамках проекта у меня реализовано это через код + enum. Таблицы не слишком большие, но много где используются эти параметры. Поэтому думаю что лучше будет переделать через отдельную таблицу(будет более понятней)